# OpenFileDialog in R Selenium

Tags: r, selenium, shiny

i am writing some tests for shiny-apps. In UI.R data we have a fileInput-Object:

`fileInput(inputId= "file", label="", accept=c(".Rdata"))`

After i click it:

`webEl <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#file")
webEl$clickElement()`

a OpenFileDialog appear. For my test i need to choose a file with OpenFileDIalog. Is there any possibility to do this with R Selenium? I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Yes you can do this you need to send keys with the filename to the appropriate element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send the name of your file to the upload DOM element. Here is an example using the [Shiny upload example app.](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/uploadfile)

```
require(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://gallery.shinyapps.io/uploadfile")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "file1")
# create a dummy csv 
testCsv <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
x <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 5:8, c = letters[1:4])
write.csv(x, testCsv, row.names = FALSE)

# post the file to the app
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(testCsv))
remDr$close()
remDr$closeServer()
```

So in the case of your code it would suffice to sent the file name to your webElement:

```
webEl$sendKeysToElement(list('path/to/my/rdata.Rdata'))
```